# Excel COUNTIFS checking for blank cells

Tags: excel

I have a COUNTIFS functions that checks a few things. These include;

- Date
- Client
- Whether a certain range is blank

The current function I have is this

```
=COUNTIFS(DateRange, ">=" & StartPeriod, DateRange, "<" & EndPeriod, ClientRange, "=" $ Client, DateSent, "<> '' ")
```

- DateRange is the range of all date,
- StartPeriod and EndPeriod are the date constraints,
- ClientRange is the range of all client names,
- Client is who will be filter for,
- **DateSent** is when the item was sent out. This is either a blank value or a date

I am trying to make sure that the DateSent is not blank, but I can't figure out how to check for it since I can't use <> "" due to the requirements of the quotes.

How can I get around this requirement in a COUNTIFS?

NOTE: Adding a helper column is not a solution I can use, the table I have is what I have to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the inverse logic. I.E. `not blank` = `cell has content` or in excel `<>""` = `"*"`

> =COUNTIFS( ......... ,DataSent,"*")

Comment: I don't think I understand. Adding `DateSent, "<>*"` just gives me the same output. Changing it to `DateSent, "=*"` just gives me 0.

Comment: I didn't use either of those equations in my solution.. Leave out the `<>`. You are searching for a any string using `*`

Comment: Looks like doing just `"<>"` gives me the right output, because using `"*"` returns the same things as `"<>*"`. Update your answer and I'll mark it correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A3:A11>=G1),--(A3:A11<=G2),--(B3:B11=G3),--(C3:C11<>""))
```

If you can't use "" for some reason then use ISNUMBER (Assuming dates are numbers, or ISTEXT if text in the sent column) e.g.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A3:A11>=G1),--(A3:A11<=G2),--(B3:B11=G3),--(ISNUMBER(C3:C11)))
```

[image: Data]

Comment: What I meant is that I wouldn't be able to do `"<> "" "` since that just closes off the statement early

Comment: It did, but I later found a more elegant solution so I just used that instead (was a tiny tweak of my code compared to rewriting it entirely)

Answer (score -1):

"<>" is fine to achieve what you need.

Comment: This seems to be in conflict with what OP writes in commments. Please explain why it is not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).